# OR TOOLS SAT Ray tracing algorithm and toggle a boolean

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat, convex-polygon

I guys, I am trying to implement a ray tracing algorithm to check if a point lies inside a polygon. I got [this python code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Point_in_polygon_problem.svg) and I am trying to implement the following part in CP-SAT

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, double *vertx, double *verty, double testx, double testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
 }
```

here you can see that there are a lot of conditions to check inside  `if()`.

**What I have tried**
I tried to implement the same code for `2 points` and `1 test point` using CP_SAT and it looks something like this:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# 2 points
vert_x1 = model.NewIntVar(1, 1, 'x1')
vert_y1 = model.NewIntVar(4, 4, 'y1')

vert_x2 = model.NewIntVar(6, 6, 'x2')
vert_y2 = model.NewIntVar(0, 0, 'y2')

# 1 test point
testx = model.NewIntVar(2, 2, 'xc')
testy = model.NewIntVar(2, 2, 'yc')

result = model.NewBoolVar("result")

# booleans for y-axis conditions
b1 = model.NewBoolVar('b1')
b2 = model.NewBoolVar('b2')
b3 = model.NewBoolVar('b3')

#booleans for x-axis conditions
c1 = model.NewBoolVar('c1')

# booleans for final decision
d1 = model.NewBoolVar('d1')
d2 = model.NewBoolVar('d2')

#temp_variable for x_conditions
diff_1 = model.NewIntVar(-100, 100, 'diff_1')
diff_2 = model.NewIntVar(-100, 100, 'diff_2')
diff_3 = model.NewIntVarFromDomain(cp_model.Domain.FromIntervals([[-100, -1]]), 'diff_3')
add_1 = model.NewIntVar(-100, 100, 'add_1')
div_1 = model.NewIntVar(-100, 100, 'div_1')
prod_1 = model.NewIntVar(-1000, 1000, 'prod_1')

"""
(verty[i] > testy) && (verty[j] > testy)
"""

#check conditions for y_axis
model.Add(vert_y1 > testy).OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
model.Add(vert_y1 <= testy).OnlyEnforceIf(b1.Not())

model.Add(vert_y2 > testy).OnlyEnforceIf(b2)
model.Add(vert_y2 <= testy).OnlyEnforceIf(b2.Not())

model.Add(b1 != b2).OnlyEnforceIf(b3)
model.Add(b1 == b2).OnlyEnforceIf(b3.Not())

"""
(testx < (vertx[j] - vertx[i]) * (testy - vert[i]) / (verty[j] - verty[i])  + vertx[i] )
"""
#check conditions for x_axis
model.Add(diff_1 == vert_x2 - vert_x1)
model.Add(diff_2 == testy - vert_y1)
model.Add(diff_3 == vert_y2 - vert_y1)
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(prod_1, diff_1, diff_2)
model.AddDivisionEquality(div_1, prod_1, diff_3 )
model.Add(add_1 == div_1 + vert_x1)

model.Add(testx < add_1).OnlyEnforceIf(c1)
model.Add(testx >= add_1).OnlyEnforceIf(c1.Not())

"""
check if both conditions are True)
"""
model.Add(c1 == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(d1)
model.Add(b3 == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(d2)

"""toggle result
(I dont know how to implement toggle)
"""
model.Add(d1 != d2).OnlyEnforceIf(result.Not())

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    print("b1 = ", solver.Value(b1))
    print("b2 = ", solver.Value(b2))
    print("b3 = ", solver.Value(b3))
    print("c1 = ", solver.Value(c1))
    print("d1 = ", solver.Value(d1))
    print("d2 = ", solver.Value(d2))
    print("result : ", solver.Value(result))
    print("")
    print("diff_1", solver.Value(diff_1))
    print("diff_2", solver.Value(diff_2))
    print("diff_3", solver.Value(diff_3))
    print("prod_1 = ", solver.Value(prod_1))
    print("div_1", solver.Value(div_1))
    print("addd_1", solver.Value(add_1))
```

this gives results for 2 points but I want to use for multiple 2d points.

**Issue: **

You can see that there is a division in the calculation having division as `diff_3` and when I write the domain of `diff_3` as:

```
diff_3 = model.NewIntVarFromDomain(cp_model.Domain.FromIntervals([[-100, -1], [1, 100]]), 'diff_3')
```

then it says the `The Divisior cannot span accross zero in constraint`

But how is it possible as the domain does not have a "0" in it.

**Also, **

How one can toggle a boolean variable in CP - SAT?

Any help will be appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to to Laurent's answer. I hereby have implemented his code for multiple points. The instance of the code is written below:

```
denum_pos = [model.NewIntVar(1, 100, 'denum_pos_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]
denum_neg = [model.NewIntVar(-100, -1, 'denum_neg_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]
denum_is_positive = [model.NewBoolVar('denum_is_positive_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]
target_pos = [model.NewIntVar(1, 100, 'target_pos_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]
target_neg = [model.NewIntVar(-100, -1, 'target_neg_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]


for i in range(0, num_points):
    j = i - 1 if i != 0 else num_points - 1
    model.Add(diff_1_arr[i] == xp[j] - xp[i])
    model.Add(diff_2_arr[i] == yc - yp[i])
    model.Add(diff_3_arr[i] == yp[j] - yp[i])
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(prod_1_arr[i], diff_1_arr[i], diff_2_arr[i])

    #perform division
    model.Add(diff_3_arr[i] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i])
    model.Add(diff_3_arr[i] < 0).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i].Not())
    
    model.Add(denum_pos[i] == diff_3_arr[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i])
    model.Add(denum_pos[i] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i].Not())
    model.Add(denum_neg[i] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i])
    model.Add(denum_neg[i] == diff_3_arr[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i].Not())
    
    model.AddDivisionEquality(target_pos[i], prod_1_arr[i], denum_pos[i])
    model.AddDivisionEquality(target_neg[i], prod_1_arr[i], denum_neg[i])
    
    model.Add(div_1_arr[i] == target_pos[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i])
    model.Add(div_1_arr[i] == target_neg[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive[i].Not())
    model.Add(add_1_arr[i] == div_1_arr[i] + xp[i])
```

And the domain of `denum` is as such:

```
diff_3_arr = [model.NewIntVar(-1000, 1000, 'diff_3_arr_{i}') for i in range(num_points)]
```

When I comment out this whole part I get some output hence there should be no problem in the other constriants.

Comment: what do you mean toggle ?

Comment: Toggle means, changing the value between True and False if any condition is not satisfied. If first point satisfies the condition then the value is True, if second point does not satisfy, then the value is changed to False.

Comment: when ?  what condition ? See https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md

Comment: So, the program is to check if the point is inside a polygon. The algorithm used to check that is Ray tracing. So if the ray , that if-condition in the above python program, passes vertex, the boolean value is changed. Like you can see in the python program or the link.

Comment: Yes, I have referred to the above link to use the Chanelling constraints. I am having an issue with the division by zero issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the division with domains spanning across 0, you need to do a little coding

```
model.AddDivisionEquality(target, numerator, denum)
```

can be encoded as follows:

create 2 variables denum_neg and denum_pos with each half domain (positive and negative).

create a Boolean variable denum_is_positive.

link denum_is_positive, denum, and denum_neg, denum_pos

```
model.Add(denum > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive)
model.Add(denum < 0).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive.Not())

model.Add(denum_pos == denum).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive)
model.Add(denum_pos == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive.Not())

model.Add(denum_neg == -1).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive)
model.Add(denum_neg == denum).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive.Not())
```

now duplicate the division

```
model.AddDivisionEquality(target_pos, numerator, denum_pos)
model.AddDivisionEquality(target_neg, numerator, denum_neg)
```

channel back with `denum_is_positive)

```
model.Add(target == target_pos).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive)
model.Add(target == target_neg).OnlyEnforceIf(denum_is_positive.Not())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Laurent. Now I just wanna know How can I toggle a single boolean variable ;(

Comment: Hi @LaurentPerron I implemented your suggestion using Loop for my application, but the thing is, the model returns INFEASIBLE. It returns something when I comment on this exact part. It is possible for you to have a quick look at it :)

I will edit the question just in case if you want to have a look.

Comment: is 1 and -1 always in the domain of denum ? (otherwise adjust). And I replaced a 1 by a -1.

Comment: Yes, 1 and -1 are always in the domain of denum. I relaced 1 by -1 still same infeasibility :((

Comment: if You want I can also post the whole code on Google Discussion forum.

Comment: I tried to comment and uncomment every line of this part. The problem seems to be when we Duplicate the division. But the domains of the target_pos and target_neg seem okay. Where can the issue be in that "duplicate division"

Comment: Please post a faulty examples on github

Comment: I have posted it on the [GOOGLE Discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/5RnyFRsh09s)